# Save files in wp7 in a location other than IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a WP7 application which downloads some files from a server. Now I am saving these files to isolated storage. Is there any option to save these files in a location other than Isolated Storage. No problem for accessing these files from outside the application.The reason is that I need to open these files and show them to the user.

Is there any option to store outside Isolated Storage? If yes, how?

Comment: NOOB is right, you can just store your files on cloud, IsolatedStorage, or Database.

Comment: Will you please give me some more explanation about cloud? Actually I am downloading the files for opening and viewing them when there is no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the ways you have to persist information in Windows Phone:

- Save to a file in Isolated Storage (with the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))
- Save in the Application Settings (with the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))
- Save to a database (that will be in turn saved in Isolated Storage)
- Send the info to some Internet webservice/remote storage
- If it is a picture file, you can save it to the Pictures Library (with the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) - [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))

There is no other access to storage in Windows Phone right now!